# Variables Reference in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, variables, visual-studio-code

Yesterday I became VSC user and found in one tutorial video record like this `'Article is ${this.article} & price is ${this.price}'` where `${this.price}` is identified as variable in scope within string. How can I do the same good thing for myself?

Comment: See template literals in javascript.

Comment: *How can I do the same thing?"  Just use it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference only in quotes, and to make template string all what needed `` instead "" or '', fuuuuu. Huge thanks to participants.